# for each loop based on 2 elements in xslt

Tags: xslt

i have a requirement, i need to repeat loop on each record and need to take substring on each occurrence. My child elements have multiple occurrence and each of them are to be mapped respectively.

Source xml.

```
<Records>
   <Record>
      <A><C1>A record information</C1></A>
      <B><C1>B record information</C1></B>
      <C><C1></C1></C>
      <D><C1>D record information</C1></D>
      <E><C1/></E>
      <F><C1>F record formation</C1></F>
      <G><C1>P1 LABOR P1 IN G1</C1></G>
      <G><C1>*P2 LABOR P2 IN G1</C1></G>
      <G><C1>P3 LABOR P3 IN G1</C1></G>
      <F><C1>F 2nd record information</C1></F>
      <G><C1>P1 LABOR P1 IN G1</C1></G>
      <G><C1>*P2 LABOR P2 IN G1</C1></G>
      <G><C1>P3 LABOR P3 IN G1</C1></G>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <A><C1>A record information</C1></A>
      <B><C1>B record information</C1></B>
      <C><C1><C1></C>
      <D><C1>D record information</C1></D>
      <E><C1/></E>
      <F><C1>F record information</C1></F>
      <G><C1>P1 LABOR P1 IN G1</C1></G>
      <G><C1>*P2 LABOR P2 IN G1</C1></G>
      <G><C1>P3 LABOR P3 IN </C1></G>
      <F><C1>F 2nd record information</C1></F>
      <G><C1>P1 LABOR P1 IN G1</C1></G>
      <G><C1>*P2 ABOR P2 IN G1</C1></G>
      <G><C1>P3 LABOR P3 IN G1</C1></G>
   </Record>
</Records>
```

my expected result it below.

```
`        <Records>
    <Record>
      <A>
        <C1>cord infor</C1>
      </A>
      <B>
        <C1>cord infor</C1>
      </B>
      <C>
        <C1></C1>
      </C>
      <D>
        <C1>cord infor</C1>
      </D>
      <E>
        <C1/>
      </E>
      <F>
        <C1>record form</C1>
      </F>
      <G>
        <C1>LABOR P1 IN LABOR P3 IN</C1>
      </G>
      <F>
        <C1>record form</C1>
      </F>
      <G>
        <C1>LABOR P1 IN LABOR P3 IN</C1>
      </G>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <A>
        <C1>cord infor</C1>
      </A>
      <B>
        <C1>cord infor</C1>
      </B>
      <C>
        <C1></C1>
      </C>
      <D>
        <C1>cord infor</C1>
      </D>
      <E>
        <C1/>
      </E>
      <F>
        <C1>record form</C1>
      </F>
      <G>
        <C1>LABOR P1 IN LABOR P3 IN</C1>
      </G>
      <F>
        <C1>record form</C1>
      </F>
      <G>
        <C1>LABOR P1 IN LABOR P3 IN</C1>
      </G>
    </Record>
  </Records> `enter code here
```

for each record i need to map elements respectively with substring function.
and need to group G elements with first occurrence of F by eliminating the G record which start with *

the number of occurrences for each F and G are dynamic.
have tried with for each with or operator but im not able to concat the G elements if i open a loop above the element name.

Please help .

Comment: This is both unreadable and incomprehensible. I suggest you ask one **specific** question at a time.

Comment: that was my requirement actually, i need to loop it on each record and make concat of G regards respective to F

Comment: didnt get you, can you pls elaborate. @michael.hor257k

Comment: No, the one who needs to elaborate is you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: oh sorry. if you were wondering about the code format i added, that becaz its not allowing me to add it as complete xml somehow. i have to remove all the spaces before i post.

Comment: im sure, if you open them in browser, it gives you the structure.

Comment: I've corrected the formatting of your input XML document. All you have to do is ensure there are at least 4 spaces before each line in the XML. If you can now do the same for the output XML that would be a great help. It may also help if you showed a sample of the output with the actual values in, rather than just functions like `substring(10,4)`. Thank you

Comment: Thanks Tim, for the idea.I have my required output schema.

Comment: i need to concat all G elements between 2 F's, while concatnating the G records, need to avoid the G record which starts with *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i need to concat all G elements between 2 F's, while concatnating the
>   G records, need to avoid the G record which starts with *

To answer this question - and **only** this question:

The following stylesheet starts by copying all nodes in the XML document except G, which is suppressed by a dedicated template. A third template adds a single G element concatenating the contents of all G elements following a F element, except those that start with a '*':

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="g" match="G" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::F[1])" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="G"/>

<xsl:template match="G[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::F]]">
    <G><C1>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('g', generate-id(preceding-sibling::F[1]))[not(starts-with(C1, '*'))]">
            <xsl:value-of select="C1"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </C1></G>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following **test input**:

```
<Records>
   <Record>
      <A><C1>A record information</C1></A>
      <B><C1>B record information</C1></B>
      <C><C1></C1></C>
      <D><C1>D record information</C1></D>
      <E><C1/></E>
      <F><C1>F1 record information</C1></F>
      <G><C1>alpha</C1></G>
      <G><C1>*bravo</C1></G>
      <G><C1>charlie</C1></G>
      <F><C1>F2 record information</C1></F>
      <G><C1>red</C1></G>
      <G><C1>*green</C1></G>
      <G><C1>blue</C1></G>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <A><C1>A record information</C1></A>
      <B><C1>B record information</C1></B>
      <C><C1></C1></C>
      <D><C1>D record information</C1></D>
      <E><C1/></E>
      <F><C1>F3 record information</C1></F>
      <G><C1>Adam</C1></G>
      <G><C1>*Betty</C1></G>
      <G><C1>Cecil</C1></G>
      <F><C1>F4 record information</C1></F>
      <G><C1>100</C1></G>
      <G><C1>*200</C1></G>
      <G><C1>300</C1></G>
   </Record>
</Records>
```

the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records>
   <Record>
      <A>
         <C1>A record information</C1>
      </A>
      <B>
         <C1>B record information</C1>
      </B>
      <C>
         <C1/>
      </C>
      <D>
         <C1>D record information</C1>
      </D>
      <E>
         <C1/>
      </E>
      <F>
         <C1>F1 record information</C1>
      </F>
      <G>
         <C1>alphacharlie</C1>
      </G>
      <F>
         <C1>F2 record information</C1>
      </F>
      <G>
         <C1>redblue</C1>
      </G>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <A>
         <C1>A record information</C1>
      </A>
      <B>
         <C1>B record information</C1>
      </B>
      <C>
         <C1/>
      </C>
      <D>
         <C1>D record information</C1>
      </D>
      <E>
         <C1/>
      </E>
      <F>
         <C1>F3 record information</C1>
      </F>
      <G>
         <C1>AdamCecil</C1>
      </G>
      <F>
         <C1>F4 record information</C1>
      </F>
      <G>
         <C1>100300</C1>
      </G>
   </Record>
</Records>
```

Comment: thanks michael, i see the response for G records grouping. same time i want to make mapping from source A to Target A by spitting it. kind of i need substring from source A to Target A same to B and C D also.

Comment: seems to be its copying the A to D records as it is, do we get a space to edit the other records as well here. that will fullfill my requirement more efficiently, otherwise i see using multiple xslts. pls suggest

Comment: @Sujan You can write a specific template for each node you do not want to be copied *as is*. If you're having difficulty with this, I suggest you post a separate question concentrating on this specific issue.

Comment: Thanks Micahel... that was helpful, will try to dig into it.